# How to programatically unaccent pandas dataframe header

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, header, unaccent

I have several pandas dataframes with different accented characters in their column names. I would like to convert accented characters to their unaccented equivalents only in column names.
I am looking for similar solutions to which I regularly use in R:
names(DT) = stringi::stri_trans_to_general('latin-ASCII', names(DT))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`unidecode` can convert accented chars to unaccented versions. Loop it across all the columns like so:

```
import unidecode

df.columns = [unidecode.unidecode(col) for col in df.columns]
```

Comment: Can also use `df.rename(columns=unidecode.unidecode)`

Comment: It definitely works! I spent 2 hours to google a solution but I haven't got a similar question neither. Thanks!

Comment: I'm glad : ) feel free to mark the question as answered.